# Why is my copy and tranpose "algorithm" slow?

Tags: excel, copy-paste, transpose, vba

```
Worksheets(ShtName).Range("D4:D91").Value = Worksheets("Builder").Range("C244:C331").Value
'MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim N As Long
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
j = 2
k = 1

Dim rownum As Long
Dim colnum As Long
Dim data, result
colnum = 1

Dim rng As Range
Dim counter As Integer

Set rng = Worksheets(ShtName).Range("D4:D91")

i = 1

For counter = 1 To rng.Rows.Count

    If rng.Cells(i) = "0" Then
        rng.Cells(i).Cells.Delete
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If

Next

With Range("D4", Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2)
data = .Value
numrows = UBound(data)
rownum = 4

Range((Cells(5, 4)), (Cells(91, 4))).Copy
Cells(4, 5).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True

Cells(5, 4).Select

Range("D5:D30").Delete Shift:=xlUp
End With
```

It's abit messy I know but wondering how I can improve it, not sure how better to ask the question either

Comment: How slow is slow? There are some improvements you could make but don't see why your code should be slow. Though looks like you haven't posted all of your code.

Comment: You probably have events that are being triggered. try disabling events and re enabling them at the end.

Comment: If your code works, I think it is best suited for [codereview.se]. You would have to reformat it, thought, to provide a meaningful Title with the intent of your code and a description of what it does, and also provide the full working code (`Sub` declarations included)

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with the delete method taking a long time when used multiple times. Instead, I use the .clear method and then sort all the blanks to the bottom at the end.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of improvements, though unlikely to be the source of a performance issue:

Instead of deleting cells (or rows or columns) in ascending order, like this:

```
For counter = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    If rng.Cells(i) = "0" Then
        rng.Cells(i).Cells.Delete
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

It is usually better in Excel to delete in descending order, like this:

```
For counter = rng.Rows.Count to 1 Step -1
    If rng.Cells(counter) = "0" Then
        rng.Cells(counter).Cells.Delete
    End If
Next
```

This eliminates the need for two "count" variables and simplifies the logic. Furthermore, it would be better to separate this loop into its own function/sub--perhaps `function DeleteCellsEqualToZero(aRange as Range) as Integer`.

Separating this and other portions of the function into separate functions/subs will also help you pinpoint the code with a performance issue.

Comment: @Robot_enthusiast feel free to upvote my answer if I've provided relevant and useful information to your question :)

Comment: I tried to but I don't have enough rep I'm afraid. Sorry about that